# JUnit testing with annotations

Tags: java, junit

Hey all I am trying to get these Unit tests to fail but can't it uses annotations, which is new to me. Any ideas would be great!

I have been trying all sorts of ways to get them to fail by either setting the test class variables to null, or trying to use if/else statements in the minimum test, but they always come out passing. Is this correct?

```
public class ValidationServiceTest extends BaseServiceTest {
    ValidationService validationService;
    ValidationException ve;
    TestDto test;
    Field f;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        validationService = new ValidationService();
        ve = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void validateNotNull(){
        try {
            validationService.validate(ve, test.xx);
            assertNotNull("testing notNull()", ve);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void validateMin(){
        try {
            validationService.validate(ve, test.xy);
            if(test.xy > f.min()){
                assertTrue("testing min()" , test.xy > -1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public class TestDto{
        @Field(notNull=true)
        public Integer xx = null;
        @Field(min=2)
        public Integer xy = -5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how we can answer without any actual information.

Comment: I am just trying to test the annotation I have in the Field.java class but they are annotated in the above class.

As of now when I I make the call to @Field(notNull=true) this means the field may NOT contain a null value; however, when trying to invoke my validate method the test passes, but I printed the output for the ve variable  and it printed null, so I am unsure where this went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do not catch Exception, mark test method with `throws Exception` instead.

The `test` field is never initialized in your test, which means it's **null**. This causes NullPointerException whenever you try to access fields of `test`. The assertion line is skipped and exception is suppressed in the catch clause. Removing the try/catch block and marking test method with `throws Exception` instead will cause the test to report error and you will see what's wrong instantly.

Comment: My previous answer was wrong actually, as there is no AssertionException. There is AssertionError thrown by assertion methods which does not extend Exception but Error. The correct explanation is here, although _Do not catch Exception_ solution is still valid.